# Why isn't awk correctly spacing my fields?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with a number of fields that I want to tweak using awk.

```
$ cat file.txt
  133     288K     280K      80K      64K  /system/bin/installd
  121     272K     264K      79K      68K  /system/bin/servicemanager
  698     248K     240K      79K      72K  /system/bin/servicemanager
 1348     248K     240K      79K      72K  /system/bin/servicemanager
  126     244K     236K      65K      56K  /system/bin/debuggerd
$ cat file.txt | awk '{print $NF $1}'
133stem/bin/installd
121stem/bin/servicemanager
698stem/bin/servicemanager
1348tem/bin/servicemanager
126stem/bin/debuggerd
```

That's not what I wanted! I was hoping for the numbers to appear on the right of the text, rather than overlapping. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect what you're seeing is due to carriage returns, probably due to Windows/DOS style CRLF line separators. You can verify by checking `cat -vte file.txt` and carrage returns will show as `^M`.  You can filter these out inline with `tr`:

```
cat file.txt | tr -d '\r' | awk '{print $NF $1}'
```

That should fix the overlapping problem. Keep in mind that `awk` won't insert an output field separator in the above unless you put a comma between `$NF` and `$1` (i.e. you won't see a space between the two)

Comment: thank you so much for this @FatalError - this just completely stumped me although I'm quite familiar with having to run dos2unix all the time on my data since I work between both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your lines end with carriage-returns before their line-feeds; that is, it looks like you've got Windows line-endings. Try running `dos2unix` on the file before running your command:

```
dos2unix file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Per other posts, you need `dos2unix file.txt` or similar.

You also need to specify some value to separate the two columns you are printing, i.e.

```
 # use the defualt value for FS
 awk '{print $NF , $1}' file.txt 

 # use a tab
 awk '{print $NF "\t" $1}' file.txt

 # use a space
 awk '{print $NF " " $1}' file.txt
```

Also note that the use of `cat file.txt |` will win you the Useless Use Of Cat award in some circles :-), so I have included a more direct solution to your problem in the samples above.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Code:    `cat file.txt |  awk '{ print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$1 }'`

Output:  288K 280K 80K 64K /system/bin/installd 133 ...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, `eol` is `\r`. Change to `\n` first.

```
mac2unix file.txt
```